# How to start Dropbox after changing username?

Tags: lubuntu, startup-applications

I work on a laptop with Linux Ubuntu 20.04 and recently get the message "Dropbox can not be started. Mostly this is an authorization failure... etc". *(translation message from Dutch)*
Even after installation with the terminal the message keeps coming.
Recently I changed my user's name in the terminal, Dropbox might not recognize me.
Anyone a tip?
Best regards,
JGF

Comment: Do you remember how Dropbox was installed? Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep -i dropbox` and `which dropbox` to the question.

Comment: Hi, I installed Dropbox both from Ubuntu depository (2019.02.14-1ubuntu1) and in the terminal. After I changed my username and de- & reinstalled Dropbox some of my old username appeared not to have left, Dropbox could not be started. Dropbox community sent me a link to an advanced reinstall which removed the old stuff and made a fresh restart possible.

Comment: Commands for a clean restart:  
    dropbox stop
    dropbox status  # Should report "not running"
    rm -rf ~/.dropbox-dist
    rm -rf /var/lib/dropbox
    rm -rf ~/.dropbox*
    sudo apt-get remove nautilus-dropbox
    sudo apt-get remove dropbox
    rm /etc/apt/source.d/dropbox
    sudo chown "$USER" "$HOME"
    sudo chown -R "$USER" ~/Dropbox
    sudo chattr -R -i ~/Dropbox
    sudo chmod -R u+rw ~/Dropbox

    Deleting any of these folders will not delete the files in your Dropbox folder.
    Restart your computer.